# How to display pixels frame by frame using Xlib to make a video sequence?

Tags: c, linux, graphics, x11

I wanted to draw pixels frame by frame using Xlib.

If I take frame size of 1100 * 1000, should I write something like this?

```
for(i=0;i<=1100;i++)
{
 for(j=0;j<=1000;j++)
  {
    XDrawPoint(arguments,i,j);
  }
}
```

However, this is only for a single frame. How to repeat it to show something like a video sequence?

Comment: that would probably be too slow,  perhaps look at the xanim source.

Answer (score 3):

To answer you actual question: get the next frame ready, then `nanosleep(2)` until it's time to show the next frame, then tell X11 to show it.  As I understand it, with VDPAU, you can get even more precise frame timing by giving a prepared frame to the server with a timestamp of when it's to be shown.  Then you don't need as good soft-realtime wakeup behaviour to get your frame shown at the right time.

Sending each pixel individually to the X server will be extremely slow.  Look into either Xv (x-video), or draw a whole pixmap locally and send that to the server.  Or OpenGL would be another API for drawing textures and showing them on screen.  Video-playing software like [mpv](http://mpv.io/) or vlc use OpenGL for video output these days, for high-quality scaling and maybe better behaviour with composited desktops.  Xv used to be the default, and still works well on almost every Linux system, even ones without good OpenGL support.  (Video-playing software doesn't just use pixmaps because they need HW support for converting from YUV to RGB, and for HW scaling to fullscreen).

In the long run, you might be better off using Qt or GTK libraries for your code.  If you don't already know low-level X11 APIs, then learning them is mostly a waste of time, IMO.  It's a better idea to write programs these days with a portable windowing library, so they integrate well into people's desktops, and can be compiled for Linux / Mac / Windows native graphics.